# how to redirect link outside project as tag <a href=""></a>

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Example: In my website I need to redirect to www.google.com. In blade engine:

```
<a href="www.google.com">Click here </a>
```

After i had clicked "Click here", It return in domain http://localhost:8000/www.google.com

So why it not redirecting to www.google.com?

Comment: There is a protocol missing. Try:  <a href="https://www.google.com">Click here </a>

Comment: thank you. But it's still return same domain in my question.

Comment: SO made a link out of it. Use http:// www. google. com (remove the whitespaces)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<a href="https://www.google.com/">Click here </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use full url like

```
<a href="https://www.google.com/">Click here </a>
After i had clicked "Click here", It return in domain
```

Answer (score 0):

`<a href="https://www.google.com/">Click here</a>` 
This will solve your problem ;) , Remember to use full URL.